# Example of showing internal vs external linkage

Tags: c, linkage

I have the following which I'm trying to set up to show the difference between a variable with global scope vs one with file/program scope:

```
// scope.c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("External: %d\n", external);
    printf("Internal (static): %d\n", internal); // should error
}
```

```
// scope_other.c
int external = 7;   // file scope, external linkage
static int internal = 6;   // file scope, internal linkage
```

And to compile with:

`$ gcc scope.c scope_other.c -o scope && ./scope`

But it seems like I'm missing something here to properly demonstrate the global vs static linkage. What would be the proper way to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have declarations of both variables in `scope.c`.

Try adding `extern int external, internal;` in `scope.c` before the definition of `main`.  This will fix the *compiler* errors you're undoubtedly seeing for both variables.  But you will still get a *linker* error for `internal` only.  If you comment out the line that prints `internal`, but leave the line that prints `external` alone, the program will compile, link and run.

Comment: thank you, that does it. Out of curiosity, why does the linker only error when `internal` is used in a function? If I don't include the `printf("Internal (static): %d\n", internal);` line, the program still runs fine.

Comment: It's perfectly legal to declare a variable that doesn't exist, so long as you never actually use it.  The compiler emits no reference to the symbol unless it is used.  See C17 6.9 (3) "no more than one".

Comment: I see, is there a `Wsomething` that I can use to show warnings in that case?

Comment: @David542: Not that I know of, and I'm not sure how it could work.  The compiler only sees one source file at a time.  It could warn whenever an object is declared but not used in the same file, but that would result in a flood of useless warnings (e.g. when you `#include <stdio.h>` but don't call every single function it declares).  And object files don't contain information about which declarations were seen, so although the linker knows which objects were defined, it's too late.